# Symfony2 undefined variable in form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am just starting out with Symfony2 . Rather than having to learn twig, I decided to implement my forms in php instead.  I followed the instructions in The Book, as follows:

in the controller:

```
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find MyEntity entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createForm(new MyEntityType(), $entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return $this->render('MyBundle:MyEntity:edit.html.php' array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'    => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form'  => $deleteForm->createView()
    ));
}
```

and in edit.html.php:

```
<form action="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('myentity_update', array('id'=>$entity->getId()))?>" method="post" <?php echo $view['form']->enctype($editForm) ?>>

   <?php echo $view['form']->widget($editForm)?>

  <p>
    <button type="submit">Save Changes</button>
  </p>
</form>
<ul class="record_actions">
<li>
    <a href="<?php $view['router']->generate('myentity') ?>">
        Back to the list
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <form action="<?php $view['router']->generate('myentity_delete', array('id'=>$entity->getId()) ) ?>" method="post">
        <?php echo $view['form']->widget($deleteForm)?>
        <button type="submit">Delete</button>
    </form>
</li>
```

when I try to display the form I get error:
Notice: Undefined variable editForm

As far as I'm aware, I have followed the instructions exactly as they are given in [The Book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html). I have tried replacing $editForm with $form in the action and template or replacing $editForm with edit_form in the template - needless to say, neither of these worked.

I would very much appreciate any suggestions as to what I should try next (or I may have to resign myself to learning twig, as at least the instructions for that seem to be correct).

Comment: can u please add the full code for both controller and html.

Comment: added all code from editAction function in controller and full code for the template

Comment: @richsage oops, sorry - done that now. not sure why I never noticed the tick mark next to the answers before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass your variable to your view as `edit_form` (the array keys are the names of the variables to use in the view):

```
return $this->render('MyBundle:MyEntity:edit.html.php' array(
    'entity'      => $entity,
    'edit_form'    => $editForm->createView(),
    'delete_form'  => $deleteForm->createView()
));
```

but you reference it in your view as `$editForm`:

```
<form action="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('myentity_update',
    array('id'=>$entity->getId()))?>" method="post" <?php echo $view['form']->enctype($editForm) ?>>
```

Decide on the same approach for both (`edit_form` vs `editForm`), and you should be good. Eg `'edit_form'` becomes `$edit_form` in the view, and similarly for `'editForm'` becoming `$editForm`.